# Set User Units when generating a PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I need to change the default user unit in a generated pdf file.  Here is a minimal example which displays, but without the correct document size.

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [ 3 0 R ]
/Count 1 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/UserUnit 2.83
/MediaBox [0 0 2440 1220]
/Contents 4 0 R >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Length 44 >>
stream
0.3 0.5 0.2 0.1 k
100 100 400 400 re
f
endstream
endobj
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000058 00000 n
0000000117 00000 n
0000000221 00000 n
trailer
<< /Size 5
/Root 1 0 R >>
startxref
309
%%EOF
```

If you open this file in a PDF viewer, it's as if the UserUnit default has not been changed.

I need to get the user units as close to millimetres as possible.  The graphics in this file are to be printed onto board then cut out with a CNC machine so there needs to be some level of accuracy with the printing.

How do you set the UserUnit value correctly?

Comment: Which pdf viewer did you test that with?

Comment: Preview 8.0 and Inkscape.

Comment: I don't have relevant experience with either. Have you tried good ol' Adobe Reader?

Comment: Besides my answer, I also have a question... why would you not simply use default user space and put the correct values there? You're introducing an additional level of calculation and rounding into the equation by using the user unit value...

Comment: I thought changing the UserUnit would make it easier for adding geometry, that is the coordinates would not have to be altered. I see what you mean about rounding. Maybe I'll try a transformation matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never assume Apple Preview does the correct thing with PDF files.

If you open this in Adobe Acrobat, the reported page size is 2436 x 1218mm, which I believe is correct for your UserUnit value.

The box looks the same size proportionally as what is shown in Preview, so I'm going to assume that one is drawn correctly as well.

Comment: Really? I guess I should get Acrobat.

Comment: I would definitely recommend to have either Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader (or some other viewer that is known to do the right thing with PDF files). Adobe Reader is free should should be an obvious choice...

Comment: ... but Acrobat is not available on Linux ...

Comment: ... but this topic was about macOS, so Linux wasn't a big issue. I'm not very familiar with Linux desktop operations, so I can't help with an alternative I'm afraid.